# Multiple Root Tags

Tags: android

It tells me that it has multiple root tags, and then takes me to the Relative Layout. I'm fairly new to this, so could someone help me form this correctly? It'd be much appreciated. I've updated it with the full Action Bar I'm trying to incorporate.This is the link to what I'm using (the first one): http://socialize.github.io/socialize-sdk-android/action_bar.html?v=v3.1.3

```
<EditText android:text="@string/tranquil_serendipity" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

```
public class ActionBarSample extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Call Socialize in onCreate
Socialize.onCreate(this, savedInstanceState);

// Your entity key. May be passed as a Bundle parameter to your activity
String entityKey = "http://www.getsocialize.com";

// Create an entity object including a name
// The Entity object is Serializable, so you could also store the whole object in the Intent
Entity entity = Entity.newInstance(entityKey, "Socialize");

// Wrap your existing view with the action bar.
// your_layout refers to the resource ID of your current layout.
View actionBarWrapped = ActionBarUtils.showActionBar(this, R.layout.actionbar, entity);

// Now set the view for your activity to be the wrapped view.
setContentView(actionBarWrapped);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();

// Call Socialize in onPause
Socialize.onPause(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

// Call Socialize in onResume
Socialize.onResume(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();

// Call Socialize in onStart
Socialize.onStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();

// Call Socialize in onStop
Socialize.onStop(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
// Call Socialize in onDestroy before the activity is destroyed
Socialize.onDestroy(this);

super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple root tags in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275533/multiple-root-tags-in-android-studio)

Comment: There needs to be one parent layout for your ux components. Hence your `ScrollView` and `ActionBarView` is wrapped in one `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: everything is normal

Comment: post the whole xml file

Comment: I'm sorry for the question, but better ask, have you tried to clean project?