# Add multiple buttons to Frame Layout (android)

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

I have an application that uses Google Maps in a frame layout. I am using alternative 2 in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901141/how-to-draw-free-hand-polygon-in-google-map-v2-in-android) (accepted) answer. When I use alternative 2, I have a single button at top of the application (Free Draw). My question is, can I add more than one button (horizontally/vertically) on the sides of this button?

I have searched online for similar questions but mostly, the answer involves two separate layouts. I am a beginner to android and do not know how to use two separate layouts. I tried using two layouts but get an error "Multiple root tags." Is there any way I can tackle this problem?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your root_map.xml will give you two buttons next to each other at the top left corner of your map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fram_map"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_draw_State"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Free Draw" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_dosomethingelse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Do Something Else" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. You can add as many buttons as you like. To control their position within the FrameLayout you have to assign gravity to each child, using the `android:layout_gravity` attribute.

Example :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button A"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button B"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Concerning your error "Multiple root tags" : [Multiple root tags in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275533/multiple-root-tags-in-android-studio)